# ajax pop up cannot load in controller

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, popup

i using click load more in codigniter, but  i have problem, before using ajax for load data its working fine, but now popup cannot show.
thanks before

```
<a href="#" id="'.$result->attachment_link.'" class="popup_gallery detail_image "></a>
```

```
var get_ekspresi = function(page){
                $("#loader_ekpresi").show();
                $.ajax({
                    url:"<?php echo site_url() ?>Home/get_ekspresi",
                    type:'GET',
                    data: {page:page}
                }).done(function(response){
                    $("#gallery_show_ekpresi").append(response);
                    $("#loader_ekpresi").hide();
                    if (response ==  "") {
                        $("#load_more_gallery_ekpresi").hide();
                    } else{
                        $('#load_more_gallery_ekpresi').data('val', ($('#load_more_gallery_ekpresi').data('val')+1));
                    }
                });
            };
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $(".popup_gallery").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
                var id = {id:$(this).attr('id')};
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>Home/gallery",
                    data: id,
                    datatype: 'json',
                    success:function(data) {
                       $('.content-image').html(data); 
                    },
                    error:function(data) {

                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

when i click image no error in console

Comment: use `Network` in `Dev tools` where `Console`, what do you see there?

Comment: @AksenP nothing error,  link "<a href="#" id="'.$result->attachment_link.'" class="popup_gallery detail_image "></a>" i put in controller

Comment: it's a very bad practise. Put it into **view** and send data via variables from **controller** into it .

Comment: @AksenP but i load data using ajax.

Comment: OK. Add in your question everything you have. **HTML & PHP & JS**